# Issue with incompatible type error on ItemWriter part of batch step

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am trying to add a new step to my Spring Batch job that will create an XLS file.  I have a reader that puts the output to a bean called CLUCReportDTO.  I am working on the blueprint of the itemWriter to create the CSV file. Here is the code

Inside the A8SPACH2 class

```
  @Autowired
   private ACH2WriteProcessor clucWriter;


  public Step jobStep020() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get(JOB.ACH2_BATCH_LOAD.getProfileName() + 
   ".js020")
            .listener(promotionListener)
            .<CLUCReportDTO, String> chunk(100)
            .reader(lockboxWirePostService.getUnappliedJes())
            .writer(clucWriter)
            .listener(listener)
            .build();
  }
```

Inside the ACH2WriteProcessor class

```
public class ACH2WriteProcessor implements ItemWriter<CLUCReportDTO>{


@Override
    public void write(List<? extends CLUCReportDTO> items) throws Exception 
    {  


    }  

 }
```

I am getting the following error in A8SPACH2: **Cannot be converted to ItemWriter< ? Super String>** .   What am I missing in the setup of either A8SPACH2 or ACH2WriteProcessor that is causing this error.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your configuration (`.<CLUCReportDTO, String> chunk(100)`), the item writer is expected to write items of type `String`, but you are declaring it to write items of type `CLUCReportDTO` (`public class ACH2WriteProcessor implements ItemWriter<CLUCReportDTO>`).

Your item writer should be declared like this:

```
public class ACH2WriteProcessor implements ItemWriter<String>{

   @Override
   public void write(List<? extends String> items) throws Exception {  

   }  
}
```

Comment: I was thinking I had to define it in the format of the Reader.   That solved the syntax error hopefully I can get the read working and the rest.  Thanks